# Google Search Console: Breadcrumbs > Missing field "position"

Tags: google-search-console, breadcrumbs

I am working on an e-commerce website. I am getting the following error on Google Search Console:

> Breadcrumbs > Missing field "position"

[image]

This is one of the URLs which has this error:

https://my-domain.com/buy-and-sell/display/2086

And this is how the page looks like:

[image]

And this is the actual breadcrumb code:

```
<ul class="nav-breakcrumb" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
        <a href="/home/browse" itemprop="item">
            <span itemprop="name">home</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
        <a href="/home/browse/home-and-garden" itemprop="item">
            <span itemprop="name">Home &amp; Garden</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
        <a href="/home/browse/home-and-garden/home-and-living" itemprop="item">
            <span itemprop="name">Home &amp; Living</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
        <a href="/home/browse/home-and-garden/home-and-living/kitchen" itemprop="item">
            <span itemprop="name">Kitchen</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I followed the sample on [schema.org/BreadcrumbList](https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList) and noticed that I am missing the position meta tag:

```
<meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
```

I also found [Google's breadcrumb testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?utm_campaign=devsite&utm_medium=rdfa&utm_source=breadcrumb) for verification. The original breadcrumb was showing the following errors:

[image]

I added the position meta tag:

```
<ul class="nav-breakcrumb" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
        <a href="/home/browse" itemprop="item">
            <span itemprop="name">Home</span>
            <meta content="1" itemprop="position">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
        <a href="/home/browse/home-and-garden" itemprop="item">
            <span itemprop="name">Home &amp; Garden</span>
            <meta content="2" itemprop="position">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
        <a href="/home/browse/home-and-garden/home-and-living" itemprop="item">
            <span itemprop="name">Home &amp; Living</span>
            <meta content="3" itemprop="position">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
        <a href="/home/browse/home-and-garden/home-and-living/kitchen" itemprop="item">
            <span itemprop="name">Kitchen</span>
            <meta content="4" itemprop="position">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and tested it again:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. Cheers!!